# Nodejs .mv() function to move files doesn't work

Tags: node.js, file-upload

Hi I'm trying to move a file with .mv() function but I get this error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/uploads/progressPhoto/c743448b-0e97-4b39-9db0-fc0b54f8c2c4-nft2.png'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/uploads/progressPhoto/c743448b-0e97-4b39-9db0-fc0b54f8c2c4-nft2.png'
}
```

Here is the code of the nodejs express controller:

```js
routerProgress.post("/upload-progress", async (req, res) => {

  const { frontPhoto } = req.files;
  const front_id = `${v4()}-${frontPhoto.name}`;

    const dirname = "/uploads/progressPhoto/";

    frontPhoto.mv(dirname + front_id, (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log("File Uploaded");
    });

});
```

Here is the file structure, the controller is in the progress.js:

[image]

I'm 100% sure that the path is correct, anyone know what could be happening??

Comment: Have you tried it with ./uploads rather than /uploads? If that didn't work, could you share your file structure?

Comment: It doesn't work, well I will edit the post and share de file structure

Comment: Have you tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mv this package? It seems to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Does the `progressPhoto` directory exist?

Comment: Yes, progressPhoto directory exists

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a while ago, but put uploads within your server directory and try using the path module thus:

```
 const path = require('path');

 let dest = path.resolve(`./uploads/progressPhoto/${front_id}`);
```

and then

```
frontPhoto.mv(dest, (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log("File Uploaded");
});
```

This will make for better transportability between dev and production environments.